# How can I learn my own port number?

Tags: command-line, lan

I have 2 different laptops, one of which is hosting a freeciv LAN server. But the first time I set it up I was testing it on the faster computer so now the program thinks both laptops have the same port number and swapping laptops hasn't helped. This actually all ties back to the problem I was trying to solve that started the whole mess because the server takes connections from it's host fine but refuses the other laptop. They are both Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I fixed the connection problem by putting the internal Ip in the host box. I still don't know why the port number is the same or how to find it but it's connecting now so I'm not complaining.

Comment: Do you mean ip address ? Ports are used by servers , for example web serves use port 80 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about ports. Both laptops do have the same port number. They have 2^16-1 port numbers (all of them) in common. They probably both use the same port to receive connections from from freeciv. This shouldn't matter.